# Choosing nuget packages would cause dependency dll hell?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-update, manage-nuget-packages

Could using nuget packages cause dependency dll hell?

Example im using two nuget packages A version 1.0.0 and B in my class library

B is also heavily dependent on new feature which is non backward compatible version of A 2.0.0.

In such a case wont i get build errors? If thats the case isnt nuget scary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the very long answer. In nuget dependecies could be private when authoring

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6614

About the same issue if you are using libraries

https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-a-single-application